# How to set Batch variable to the volume label of specific drive letter?

Tags: cmd, windows-10

I want to write a .BAT file (on Win 10) which gets the volume label of the optical disk mounted at E: and assigns it to a variable so that I can then create a folder on another drive which has the same name as the volume label.

The `vol` command returns 2 lines of text (with the volume label at the end of the first line). Is there a command which will return the volume label *only*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FOR /F "tokens=6" %a IN ('vol c:') DO SET var=%a
```

This should do. When you run `echo %var%` it will show the volume label only

Make sure to change the `vol c:` to your desired volume!

EDIT:

If the Volume label has 2 words, use `FOR /F "tokens=6-7" %a IN ('vol c:') DO SET var=%a`

If it has 3 words Just change the `"tokens=6"` to `"tokens=6-7,8"`

Hope this helps!